# Read data from SQL Server 2014 in Jupiter Notebook

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to read data from sql server 2014 AdventureWorks2014 database. i wrote the below code in python jupyter note book

```
import pandas
import pyodbc
#Connection sting Diver, server, database, Authentication
connection = pyodbc.connect("Driver ={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};"
                           "Server =JONWAY01\SQLSERVER2014;"
                           "Database=AdventureWorks2014;"
                           "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
#create df
df = pandas.read_sql('SELECT *FROM HumanResources.Employee',connection)
connection.close()
df.head()
```

when i run the code it gives error

```
InterfaceError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-8e663d2a3f56> in <module>
      2 import pyodbc
      3 #Connection sting Diver, server, database, Authentication
----> 4 connection = pyodbc.connect("Driver ={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};"
      5                            "Server =JONWAY01\SQLSERVER2014;"
      6                            "Database=AdventureWorks2014;"

InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

is there anything i am doing wrong? Please help
Thanks

Comment: Some people are just here to down vote without offering any solution to question asked. If you want to down vote. first offer solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it or not, you can't have a space after the keyword `Driver`.  Change it as follows, and so long as you have the ODBC driver installed, you're good-to-go.

```
connection = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};"
                           "Server=JONWAY01\SQLSERVER2014;"
                           "Database=AdventureWorks2014;"
                           "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
```